# Performance issue with PrimeNG TurboTable

Tags: angular5, primeng, typescript2.0, webpack-3, primeng-turbotable

I am using PrimeNG TurboTable with nested rows.While loading data to the TurboTable getting serious performance issues,like the rendering takes around 30 seconds and it takes more than 10 seconds to become stable,data is loaded from the server, and the data received from the server is quite fast. Has anyone else faced problem. 
If yes, how were you able to fix the same.

**html**

```html
<p-table [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Vin</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-columns="columns" let-car>
        <tr>
            <td>{{car.vin}}</td>
            <td>{{car.year}}</td>
            <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
            <td>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of sales"
            <a [ngClass]="{'active':car.order==item.order,'inactive':car.order > item.order}">
                                    <i class="fa {{item.icon}}"></i>
                                </a>
            </li>
           </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**ts**

```js
  this.cars =[
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "Orange", "vin": "dsad231ff","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr","order"=24},
        {"brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh","order"=2},
        {"brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "Orange", "vin": "hrtwy34","order"=5},
        {"brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr","order"=10},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},
        {"brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5","order"=17},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=20},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=3},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=23},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=6},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=1},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=4},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=8},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=19},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=12},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=11},
        {"brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s","order"=24},
        {"brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "Orange", "vin": "greg34","order"=15},

];
```

**Separate List**

```js
   this.sales = [
            { brand: 'Apple', lastYearSale: '51%',thisYearProfit: '$43,342',"order"=1,"icon"="fa-flag-o" },
            { brand: 'Samsung', lastYearSale: '83%',thisYearProfit: '$312,122',"order"=2,"icon":"fa-address-card" },
            { brand: 'Microsoft', lastYearSale: '38%', thisYearProfit: '$8,500',"order"=3,"icon":"fa-eye" },
            { brand: 'Philips', lastYearSale: '49%',thisYearProfit: '$650,323',"order"=4,"icon":"fa-address-card" },
            { brand: 'Song', lastYearSale: '17%',thisYearProfit: '500,332' ,"order"=5,"icon":"fa-fax"},
            { brand: 'LG', lastYearSale: '52%',thisYearProfit: '$150,005',"order"=6,"icon":"fa-circle" },
            { brand: 'Sharp', lastYearSale: '82%',thisYearProfit: '$100,214' ,"order"=7,"icon":"fa-folder"},
            { brand: 'Panasonic', lastYearSale: '44%',thisYearProfit: '$53,322',"order"=8,"icon":"fa-address-book-o" },
            { brand: 'HTC', lastYearSale: '90%',thisYearProfit: '$296,232',"order"=9,"icon"="fa-bluetooth-b"  },
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=10,"icon"="fa-address-book-o"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=11,"icon"="fa-bath"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=12,"icon"="fa-address-card"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=13,"icon"="fa-bluetooth-b"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=14,"icon"="fa-eye"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=15,"icon"="fa-circle"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=16,"icon"="fa-fax"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=17,"icon"="fa-address-book-o"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=18,"icon"="fa-address-card"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=19,"icon"="fa-bluetooth-b"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=20,"icon"="fa-eye"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=21,"icon"="fa-fax"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=22,"icon"="fa-circle"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=23,"icon"="fa-folder"},
            { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%',thisYearProfit: '$12,533',"order"=24,"icon"="fa-flag-o"}
        ];
```

Comment: Are you use is it the TurboTable? Performance of p-table is more or less same as *ngFor, try with ngFor to render your data to see how much it differs. If you are getting your data from the server, what's up with the arrays like cars and sales? What you describe and your code does not match. I've tried your case and it opens up instantly.

Comment: @CagatayCivici Yes i am using TurboTable. If the array contains more than 100 records means it renders very slow. Ex: cars:100 records & 21 records for sales rendering takes around 20 seconds and it takes more than 10 seconds to become stable.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe check the updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/mB8h3H4evQIyQHXhhFcX?p=preview

Comment: @Antikhippe check the updated plunker and help me to solve that issue.

Comment: @CagatayCivici check the updated plunker the rendering of data is very slow in TurboTable.https://plnkr.co/edit/mB8h3H4evQIyQHXhhFcX?p=preview

Comment: @Antikhippe check the updated plunker link and help to solve this issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not TurboTable but your last column where you display 24 icons for each of your 3401 lines.

It will take quite a few seconds to display 81624 icons, even outside a table. To convince you, try this :

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
  <li *ngFor="let item of sales">
    <i class="fa {{item.icon}}"></i>
  </li>
</div>
```

You will have same performance issue.

---

To solve your problem, why don't you use pagination ? This will be very fast :

```
<p-table [value]="cars" sortField="brand" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10">
    ...
</p-table>
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UIiXvrSyNyWyUAz8QxPQ?p=preview)

Comment: If the last column  contains 10 icons for each of 2000 records with pagination is very slow. Is there is any way to solve this issue.

Comment: No, it's not that long, see my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UIiXvrSyNyWyUAz8QxPQ?p=preview)